# Entity Framework Not Adding Multiple Objects In A Domain Class To Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Entity Framework and trying to understand how to do this in a ASP.Net MVC 4 application.

I have an Appointment object that contains a Customer object (customer information) and a DateTime for the appointment. I can't seem to figure out how to store the customer object correctly.

Looking at the way I am doing things now I am thinking I should store the customer ID, but I don't know how to retrieve the customer information later (do I use the Model? Another Domain class "AppointmentDetails"? Should I use a service layer object?)

```
   public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDateTime { get; set; }

        public Appointment()
        {

        }

        public Appointment(Customer customer, DateTime appointmentDateTime)
        {
            Customer = customer;
            AppointmentDateTime = appointmentDateTime;
        }
    }
```

Customer.cs

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {

        }

        public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string city, string province, string phone, string email)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Address = address;
            City = city;
            Province = province;
            Phone = phone;
            Email = email;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post more code..Here Customer is a class. You have to define it

Comment: What code do you want to see? I have an AppointmentService, Repository (DbContext), Controller, Model. It's a lot to post all of it? I can if that's what is needed.

Comment: do you have defined Customer Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I've always used Entity Framework following a DB first approach, but I believe your classes  should store something like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointment{ get; set; } // which will be used to access your Customer's appointments.
```

in your Customer class, while in your Appointment class you would have:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

How did you create those classes? If you use the Model designer, it generates the necessary attributes to connect your classes.

Comment: I created the models and used code first to generate the tables. I was wondering though about the way my flow is and thought perhaps having the appointment store the customer ID only and use my service to retrieve the customer information... problem was I couldn't figure out where to store the customer information if my appointment class only had a customer ID property. Never thought to use virtual properties. Thanks!