# How to create view for unknown count of list item in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a new Question Answer Website.I have no idea how to save multiple option.
I don't know how option a question have.
My Model is

```
 public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        public List<Options> Options { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string CreateDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
```

Can you help How to save multiple option in database

could you please help me??????

Comment: Hi thanks for your advise but my problem is by using model binding i did not drop down for auto generated view 
Method  
write click on the action
add view 
choose model then 
click add view
all fields are added to auto generated view but i did not get Options field as a dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by "option", but:

Have this in your Question class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; } // which will be used to access your Question's options appointments.
```

and

```
public int QuestionID { get; set; }             // The ID of the question that this option belong to
public virtual Question Question { get; set; }  // The question that this option belong to
```

in your Option class if you want a one to many relationship between Question and Option ("one question may have many options, but one option may have belong to only one question") or

```
public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

if you want a many to many relationship ("one question may have many options and one option nay belong to many questions") with no linking table.

I have answered a similar question here: [Entity Framework Not Adding Multiple Objects In A Domain Class To Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525663/entity-framework-not-adding-multiple-objects-in-a-domain-class-to-database/18527836#18527836).

As for the view, you can use something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Option.ToList().Count(); i++){
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Option.ToList()[i]);  // Create an EditorFor template for your "question" and use it here. 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I don't really understand tour data model or business logic but if you want a Dropdown for your options, do something like:
- Add a SelectList to the Viewbag on your controller method:

```
ViewBag.Answer= new SelectList(question.Options, "Name_of_yuour_Option_id_field", "Name_of_a_field_that_describes_your_Option");
```

- And then on your View:

  @Html.DropDownList("Answer", String.Empty)
- Again, I don't fully understand your data model, but I believe that if your "answer" is one of the options, then instead of `public string Answer { get; set; }` you should have `public int AnswerID { get; set; } // where AnswerID will hold the id of the selected option.`

I hope this helps you go further. Have also a look at stackoverflow questions about dropdowns (e.g.  [How to fill dropdownlist for MVC4 razor views (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574290/how-to-fill-dropdownlist-for-mvc4-razor-views-c))